Sentry events displayed inappropriately while filtering
I have integrated Sentry, to track exceptions that arise in my app. Since the application was used by multiple users, the user ID was also logged which differs for every user. The exceptions are logged properly in Sentry. My issue is that the most recent logged exception was shown when filtering for the particular user using a unique ID. Why is it displayed incorrectly? or did I filter incorrectly?
Added sample code and screenshots for your reference.
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn = 'My dsn';
    },
    appRunner: () => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
  Sentry.configureScope(
    (scope) => scope..setUser(SentryUser(id: generateRandomString(5))),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sentry',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _throwError() {
    throw IsolateSpawnException(generateRandomString(10));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Sentry Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Press the button to throw an error:',
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _throwError,
              child: const Text('Throw Error'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

String generateRandomString(int length) {
  const String chars =
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
  Random random = Random();

  return List.generate(length, (index) => chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)])
      .join();
}

Filtered with ID 1234

Note the differences between the title and content on the overview page.

In this image see the User and Error title.

Why are the most recent logged exception details displayed when filtering using a unique ID? It must be shown the errors of the user who is currently filtered.
